# How do I know if the user made changes so I can save state when needed?

Tags: c#, .net

My app is kind of an editor where the user can drag and drop objects over a canvas, and change N properties on the objects. How can I know if the user has made changes on the app in order to prompt him whether he wants to save these changes or not? One way is to create a IsDirty property but this means I would have to add a line of code in many places, maybe another way could be create a virtual save, and then compare the real saved file with the virtual saved file; is there another way?

Comment: Those are the only two ways that I know of, and I go for the "cheaper" `IsDirty` flag as it is never intensive to track that computationally.

Comment: I recommend that you handle events fired up by the objects and the set isDirty flag in there.

Answer (score 1):

A single `IsDirty` flag that gets set to `true` when anything changes would be the right way to do this. It is the least expensive way to track this piece of state.

Saving would set it back to `false`.

Comment: In addition implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in a base class and change the IsDirty property accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the second option that comparing the virtual file with the real saved one, because it's easier than set `IsDirty` flag in everywhere (all possible event handlers) and you might forget set it later after some changes.

Comment: I would also recommend this approach, as long as the serialization is relatively cheap.  You can also use the pre-serialized data for saving to disk (my guess is that the most likely use case is the user wants to Save the changes), so you actually save a small amount of time after the confirmation (though the I/O is probably slower than the serialization into memory.)  Tracking IsDirty adds complexity and is best avoided unless you need it for other reasons (if you eventually add Undo/Redo support, you'll need something more sophisticated, at which point you get the 'IsDirty' for free.)

Answer (score 0):

I think both technics you described are ok, the IsDirty method could be very fast at runtime because you do not have to serialize and compare, it could imply some changes around but it's not bad by design.

Answer (score 0):

If the user changes some property and then changes it back to its original value, the `IsDirty` flag would indicate that he needs to save, while the "virtual save" method would indicate that he does not need to save.

Which one you choose partially depends on what semantics you want.